# Redirect dynamic URL with question mark to the parent link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to redirect the dynamic URL below 
http://www.example.co.uk/case-studies/detail.php?study_ID=14

To

http://www.example.co.uk/case-studies/

without any success. Could anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^study_ID=14$
RewriteRule ^case-studies/detail\.php$ /case-studies/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will try it as soon as possible tomorrow at work. I didn't have time today.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is not working. sorry for taking long time to try and give feedback. There have been some work tasks I needed to finish first. Thanks again